Conditionally serve static files based on authenticated user filesystem permissions
I have some files in a directory that I'd like to serve with Apache. I've configured Kerberos authentication with mod_auth_gssapi so I have the username in the REMOTE_USER environment variable. I'd like to serve the requested file from said directory, but only do so if the Linux user that corresponds to REMOTE_USER has read access to that file.
My current approach was to write a small Flask app that runs something like sudo -u REMOTE_USER test -r FILE_PATH and return either the file (using app.send_static_file()) or HTTP 401, but Flask is inefficient at serving large static files. I'd like something that can comfortably serve files in the 1-5 GB range.
What's the best way to do this?
